# Mailchimp editor integrate with my website

Tags: drag-and-drop, editor, mailchimp

Is it possible to integrate Mailchimp Drag & Drop editor to my webpage? (http://blog.mailchimp.com/introducing-mailchimps-new-editor/) In my website users need to design a Email template & i need one drag & drop editor exactly like MailChimp. Does mailchimp provide any widget or something that i can use in my website to get that editor integrated into my website? (I already googled a lot reg the same, could'nt find anything like it)

Answer (score 0):

did you find something similar?
I'm afraid that it's not possible to use MailChimp editor in your own web.... 
It seems to me one of the best email template editor around,

The only idea I had is to let my customer use Mailchimp and export it into my web application. 
Not quite the same but...